# Threejs skydome and Tweenmax

Tags: javascript, gsap

I've been trying to animate the colors of a skydome in threejs with Tweenmax but all my attempts failed.

Does anyone has a clue how to do that? Thanks a lot.

```
//////// SKYBOX////////
    var vertexShader = document.getElementById('sky-vertex').textContent, fragmentShader = document.getElementById('sky-fragment').textContent;
       var uniforms = {
    topColor: {type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(blue)}, //autour
    bottomColor: {type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(blue)}, //milieu
    offset: {type: "f", value: 30}, 
    exponent: {type: "f", value: 0.18}
};

var elem = document.getElementById('sky-fragment')
var blueFirst =  new THREE.Color( 0x08088A ).getHex();
var blueSecond = new THREE.Color( 0x81F7F3 ).getHex(); 
var blue = TweenMax.fromTo(elem,0.5,{color: blueFirst},{color: blueSecond});

var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyGeometry, skyMaterial );
scene.add( skyBox );
```

Comment: Hi, Victoria! Can you specify why your code not work exactly? Do you receive some error?

Comment: Hi Dherik, thanks for answering!
I think I don't manage the Tweenmax code properly. 
I updated what i tried in the code above.

Comment: Hi Dherik, so I managed to improve a bit the thing as it is running now, but nothing is happening with the color still. Let me know if you can give me a hand :) thank you so much
I updated the code above

Comment: @VictoriaDuchatelle possible for you to create a jsFiddle or a codepen please?